# How to load bootstrap and dependencies with npm inside vue powered chrome extension

Tags: vue.js, npm, google-chrome-extension, vuex

I'm learning how to use webpack, vue and vuex to create a simple chrome extension. While I'm trying to figure out how to use mutations to track socket.io events in my chrome extension, I have a problem to load bootstrap 4 inside the extension. I've used the path where the node modules folder is located, but I get a file not found and I'm not able to load bootstrap. Can anyone help me? I've used npm to install bootstrap.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Here I'm Messenger</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <% if (NODE_ENV === 'development') { %>
  <!-- Load some resources only in development environment -->
  <% } %>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're loading the extension from `dist` the href will be `"/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: ok, thanks. This means that all the dependency that I will install needs to be loaded in the same way right?

Comment: I've tried as suggested to set the path to `/css/bootstrap.min.css` but the problem will remain. The css folder not exist inside the dist folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding the `CopyWebpackPlugin` to your webpack configuration so you can pull node modules into your distribution.

reference: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/

```
const plugins = [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [
      { from: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', to: './dist/css/' },
    ],
  ),
];
```

You should then be able to update the `href` to use the copy in your `dist` folder `href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"`